# loop stops after a function with an eval and process substitution

Tags: bash, eval, process-substitution

**Context**

I have a script that iterates over a list. At each iteration it is expected to invoke a function that constructs a 'diff' command for comparing two remote files via 'eval'.

The 'diff' command gets its inputs through two process substitutions where each one cats a remote file via 'ssh' that performs a passwordless authentication (through public/private keys).

The 'diff' and 'ssh' executions have been tested out of the script and they work fine.

**Code**

Here I post a very short version of my script which however produces the same problem:

```
#!/bin/bash
func(){
   NUM=$1
   echo "func $NUM"
   COMMAND="diff <(ssh user1@server1 'cat file1' ) <(ssh user2@server2 'cat file2' )"
   eval "${COMMAND}"  1>/dev/null
   RESULT=$?
}

LIST="1
2
3
4
5"

echo "$LIST" | while read NUM ; do
   echo "main $NUM"
   func $NUM
done
```

**Expected result**

```
main 1
func 1
main 2
func 2
main 3
func 3
main 4
func 4
main 5
func 5
```

**Problem**

The script stops after the first iteration:

```
main 1
func 1
```

**Question**

Do you know why the loop stops? and how to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not the eval nor the process substitution. It's `ssh`.

`ssh` by default passes `stdin` through to the command it runs on the remote server (and passes `stdout` back from the remote command). That makes it possible to use in a pipeline. However, in this case you don't want `ssh` to touch `stdin` since you are using it yourself for the loop.

You can easily get `ssh` to not use `stdin`, either by using the `-n` command line option, or by redirecting `stdin` to `/dev/null`:

```
ssh -n user1@server1 'cat file1'
ssh user1@server1 'cat file1' < /dev/null
```

The latter would also work in the calling function:

```
echo "$LIST" | while read NUM ; do
   echo "main $NUM"
   func $NUM < /dev/null
done
```

---

I suppose you don't want a lecture on the evils of eval, but I feel obliged to mention that using `eval` in this fashion is probably unnecessary. I presume you are doing it in order to build up a command which uses process substitution. You can, instead, build up an environment with process substitutions using `exec`, such as:

```
exec 10< <(ssh -n user1@server1 'cat file1')
```

Comment: Thanks four the good explanation and the advice about exec.